# How to programmatically change a color of a column in a DataGridView bound to a BindingSource with a custom class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

DataSource of a BindingSource is a class with some public properties. Columns of the grid were created like this:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn vendorIDColumn =
           new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
           {
               MinimumWidth = 50,
               FillWeight = 20,
               DataPropertyName = "VendorID",
               HeaderText = "Vendor ID",
               AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
           };
        grid.Columns.Add(vendorIDColumn);
```

DataGridView's property "AutoGenerateColumns" were set to 'false'. 
Tried `grid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the backcolor of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ?

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn vendorIDColumn =
       new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
       {
           MinimumWidth = 50,
           FillWeight = 20,
           DataPropertyName = "VendorID",
           HeaderText = "Vendor ID",
           AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
           BackColor = Color.Red;
       };
    grid.Columns.Add(vendorIDColumn);
```

Comment: Even if I can set the color when columns are created/added I need to be able to change the color during the execution in a different method.(analyzing bound data and then changing the color)

Comment: In that case you want to listen for the event for when things are drawn. Cant recall the event name at home, but when its presented you change the backcolor then.